# Как передать переменную между фрагментами?

Tags: android

У меня есть класс "Fragment2" и класс "Fragment3" . В классе "Fragment2" есть переменная "sendProgress"  . Как передать эту переменную классу "Fragment3

Класс Fragment2

```
 public class Fragment2 extends Fragment  {

private int sendProgress = 0;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SeekBar seekbar1 = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
    seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
            sendProgress = progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

    });
}
```

}

и класс Fragment3

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3,container,false);
}
```

}

Comment: Мне интересно это как может возникнуть такой кейс, у вас 2 фрагмента на 1 экране?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, master -> detail навскидку из реальных кейсов.

Comment: master detail flow вы в ячейке будете двигать seek чтоб изменялся другой фрагмент, этот паттерн используется для навигации для элементов. Там другая логика. Я допуская что это возможно, мне просто инетерсно.

Comment: У меня в Fragment2 есть SeekBar  , после того как пользователь передвинет seekbar и нажатия на кнопку (она потом появиться ) ,значение от seekbar присваивается переменной sendProgress . Происходит переход на Fragment3 .После этого эта переменная должна передаться в Fragment3 где будет textview , так вот как передать эту переменную ?

Comment: ну вот ч.т.д  =) Теперь вашу задачу в разы легче решить, просто я так и подумал что вы описали её очень некорректно и решил задать такой вопрос. Для простого решения может просто писать переменную в той активити в которой у вас FragmetnManager управляет фрагментами, при переходе на фрагмент3, передавать свой sendProgress.

Comment: А что нужно дописать в FragmentManager чтобы передать sendProgress ?)

Comment: вы получаете seekbar из Activity, он у вас точно в фрагменте ? ))

Comment: Да, точно seekbar находиться в Fragment2

Answer (score 4):

Я сделал простой пример, для того чтобы быстро показать логику, передачи аргумента в фрагмент.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int seekBarPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonShowOne = findViewById(R.id.btn_show_1);
        Button buttonShowTwo = findViewById(R.id.btn_show_2);

        buttonShowOne.setOnClickListener(v -> replaceFragment(OneFragment.newInstance()));
        buttonShowTwo.setOnClickListener(v -> replaceFragment(TwoFragment.newInstance(seekBarPosition)));
    }

    public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragment_spot, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(int seekBarPosition) {
        this.seekBarPosition = seekBarPosition;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="shwarz.senddatabetweenfragments.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragment_spot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OneFragment.java**

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    @NonNull
    public static OneFragment newInstance() {
        return new OneFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_fragment, container, false);
        SeekBar seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onProgressChanged(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**one_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="OneFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**TwoFragment.java**

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

    private int mParam1;
    private TextView tvSeek;


    public static TwoFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        TwoFragment fragment = new TwoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) mParam1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_fragment, container, false);
        tvSeek = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_seek);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tvSeek.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"Seek on: %d", mParam1));
    }
}
```

**two_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="TwoFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="SeekPositionHere"
        android:id="@+id/tv_seek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]